# Webpack Sass compilation fails due to incompatible units

Tags: webpack, sass, zurb-foundation

I am upgrading an old project that was using Grunt to Webpack 4 and the transition has been pretty seamless. Everything compiles correctly, except for sass files.

When building webpack, I am greeted with the following error:

```
./src/assets/scss/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'rem*rem'.
        on line 27 of node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/forms/_input-group.scss, in mixin `foundation-form-prepostfix`
        from line 30 of node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/forms/_forms.scss, in mixin `foundation-forms`
        from line 10 of src/assets/scss/_custom-foundation.scss
        from line 5 of /home/rogelio/Desktop/localdev/Home/src/assets/scss/styles.scss
>>   $height: $height: ($input-font-size * $input-line-height) + (get-side($input-padding, 'top') + get-side($input-padding, 'bottom')) - rem-calc(1);
   -----------^
```

The culprit is the `_input-group.scss` file in the `forms/` folder that's part of the `foundation-sites` package. If I hard code the `$height` variable to any value, then the build compiles successfully. It's really just that single line that is preventing the build from completing.

Here are my sass variables that are used inside the `$height` variable:

- $input-font-size: 0.9375rem;
- $input-line-height: 1rem;
- $input-padding: 0.5rem;

Question: Any idea why this is erroring out?

Additional Info:

I am using `foundation-sites@6.4.1`.
I am using `node-sass` alongside `sass-loader`. I even tried swapping to the dart `sass` implementation but still got the same error.

Here's a very simplified version of my webpack config:

```js
// webpack.config.js

const loaders = {
    sass: {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
    },
    postCss: {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
            plugins: postCssPlugins,
        },
    },
    css: {
        loader: 'css-loader',
    },
    miniCssExtract: {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    },
}

export const config = {
  module: {
      test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
      use: [loaders.miniCssExtract, loaders.css, loaders.postCss, loaders.sass],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing this as I found a solution. I upgraded to v6.4.3 and that seemed to fix my issue.

Seems like in v6.4.3 the line got changed to:

```
 $height: ($input-font-size + $form-spacing * 1.5);
```

Much more simplified and solves the problem I was having!